# jQuery problem with change event and IE8

Tags: asp.net, jquery, events

There is a bug in jQuery 1.4.2 that makes change event on select-element getting fired twice when using both DOM-event and a jQuery event, and this only on IE7/8.
Here is the test code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       jQuery(document).ready(function() {

         jQuery(".myDropDown").change(function() {


         });

       });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <select class="myDropDown" onchange="alert('hello');">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update**:
Another view of the problem, actually this is the real problem we have with our application. Binding a live change event on a selector that isn't even touching the select-element with DOM-event also causes double firing.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       jQuery(document).ready(function() {

         jQuery(".someSelectThatDoesNotExist").live("change", function() {


         });

       });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <select class="myDropDown" onchange="alert('hello');">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Ticket to actual bug: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6593

This causes alot of trouble for us in our application cause we use both ASP.NET-events mixed with jQuery and once you hook up a change event on any element every select (dropdown) gets this double firing problem.

Is there anyone who knows a way around this in the meantime until this issue is fixed?

Comment: Do you need the event to propagate?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you need propagation behavior, etc...I don't think it's possible, this is a 1.4.2 core/IE8 bug that'll need an additional check in jQuery core to fix.

Comment: @Nick: What do you mean by propagate? I want it to work like the other browsers, the event only firing once.

Comment: @Marcus - Does the event need to bubble up, e.g. are you using `.live()` or `.delegate()` or any other bubble capture in a parent element?

Comment: @Nick: The first thing I tried was using live/delegation instead of straightforward binding. The interesting thing is that it changes the order the events are fired, but it didn't fix the issue. I did manage one solution though.

Comment: @Andy - I was asking because the appropriate (as possible without changing core) way to fix it would be in the right order, but nor propagate.  Your solution below doesn't cover the situation he is probably dealing with, the auto-postback.  It would submit the form before the value was set, or validation was done, depending on event order.  Picture for example `$("form").submit()` above that, with `setTimeout()` the `onchange` would run *after* the submit, causing some issues :)

Comment: @Nick: No, there is no .live() on the troublesome select-elements, only __doPostPack(...) in the onChange.

Comment: @Nick Craver, the timer in my solution just unsets the DOM level 0 handler to prevent the second event trigger which is fired separately by jQuery.  I don't think it would have any adverse affects.

Comment: @Andy - It changes the order though, `setTimeout()` won't fire until the current thread context finished, which is after any handlers, including those depending on a bubble of this or other events.  You should also test the `onchange` being a setTimeout itself (which is the case here), you're changing the `this` context :)

Comment: @Nick: the order of events should never be thoroughly relied upon anyway, and without my code, in IE8 the jQuery handler *always* runs before the DOM 0 handler which is still the case in my workaround.  The `this` problem is an easy work around, but not relevant.  I see your point about the form submit and I think the only real solution, *if that is the case*, is to remove the DOM 0 handler and rely on jQuery only.

Comment: @Andy: "is to remove the DOM 0 handler and rely on jQuery only". This is how we solved it for now.

Comment: @Marcus: did you try my solution below?

Comment: @Andy: The solution will probably work in general, but I forgot to mention/show our problem correctly in my example above. The bug shows itself even if the change-binding occurs on a totaly different select-element than the one with the DOM event. So your solution won't work my case because the jquery-change-code won't run.

Comment: @Marcus: then I would stick with your current solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to raise this question from the dead but jquery finally fixed this bug in version 1.7 which was recently released.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Then you are the lucky one getting an answer checked :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a play around with the bug and there doesn't appear to be any obvious workaround.  In my testing I found that the second change event is triggered by jQuery, so I managed to knock together a quick solution that involves removing the DOM 0 event handler and applying it again on a timer that executes immediately when the thread completes:

```
     jQuery(".myDropDown").change(function() {
         if ($.browser.msie) {
             var dd = $(this)[0], 
                 oc = dd.onchange;
             dd.onchange = null;
             window.setTimeout(function () {
               dd.onchange = oc;
             }, 0);
          }
     });
```

This works fine for me in IE8, just one "hello" alert appears, although you might want to add an IE check in there.  <del>Or not, it probably won't make a difference</del> It definitely needs that check and I've added it to the sample.  [Here's my fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ukado3).

The only other solution would be to remove the DOM 0 handler and use the jQuery handler only.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the control and add the clone immediately after the intended one and assign the event, then remove the control:

```
if ($.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 8 || parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 7)) {
    var btn2 = $(btn).clone();
    $(btn).after(btn2);
    $(btn).remove();
    $(btn2).bind("click", function () {
        //your function here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
jQuery(".myDropDown").removeAttr('onchange').change(function() {

 alert(0);
});
```

Comment: Then it wouldn't fire at all :)

Comment: ahhh... hmmm... can you please tell me why is that so nick?.... ;) well, I have not tried it though..

Comment: Sure :) Here's a demo, feel free to try your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfjBH/ The `onchange` handler is what's firing twice, if you remove it, there's noting to fire.  The current bug is he's getting 2 alerts in IE8.  As a general rule, don't treat attributes as events (even though they're *declared* that way), they're not *really* related and it only works in IE IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

We actually solve the problem another way, since this is specific to IE, ASP.NET and select element, we use the following code:

```
$(function () {
if ($.browser.msie) {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(function() {
        $('select[onchange]:not(.iefixed)')
            .addClass('iefixed')
            .each(function () {
                var self = $(this), dd = self[0], action = self.attr('onchange');
                self.removeAttr('onchange').change(action);
                dd.onpropertychange = function() { dd.blur(); };
            });
    });
}
});
```

1. This make sure that the fix is only applied to the select element that has autopostback set to true (onchange) once.
2. Basically we rely on jQuery to fire the change event for us, but in order for IE to do that, we need to trigger element blur event when onpropertychange happens.