# blur() causing double postback on a dropdownlist set to autopostback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a page in my application where blur() is wired up to the dropdownlist's onchange event using jquery.  This drowndownlist is set to autopostback.  The blur is there to remove focus from the dropdown when a selection is made.  I won't go into the details about why this is done.

Adding blur() to the onchange event causes double postbacks.  This doesn't happen on every selection, but very frequently a double postback occurs.  I can see this in the trace.axd which shows two postbacks with the same timestamp.

I've been able to reproduce this with a simple sample page.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["log"] = string.Format("{0}value={1}<br/>", Session["log"], DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            Session["Counter"] = (int)Session["Counter"] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Session["log"] = string.Empty;
            Session["counter"] = 0;
        }


    }
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").change(function (e) {

            e.target.blur();

        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <h2>
        Double Postback
    </h2>
    <p>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%=Session["counter"] %><br />
    <%=Session["log"] %>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The session stuff in there is to log (more easily than trace.axd) when this occurs. You'll see two duplicate log values spit out to the screen.  I'm using ASP.NET 4.0.

Can anyone tell me why using document.ready to add blur to onchange would cause a double postback?  Seems like it must somehow be tripping a second onchange event.

**EDIT: This appears to only happen on IE (IE8 is what I'm using) Chrome and Firefox don't exhibit the double postback.**

Looks like this issue is related to [jQuery problem with change event and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061106/jquery-problem-with-change-event-and-ie8)

Comment: Confirm that there are no empty src attributes when this condition occurs